# Multiple lambda functions in zipped list not executing

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, lambda, list-comprehension

I want to execute multiple functions that have different arguments when a condition is satisfied, but I never get any of them executed:

```
conditions = [condition1, condition2, condition3]
functions = [lambda: self._f(), lambda x: self._f2(a), lambda x,y: self._f3(b, c)]

for condition, function in zip(conditions, functions):
    if condition:
        function() # execute the proper function with 0, 1 or 2 arguments
        break

def _f():
    print('function1 with no arguments')

def _f2(x):
    print(f'function2 with one argument {x}')

def _f3(x, y):
    print(f'function2 with two arguments {x} and {y}')
```

But when the condition is satisfied, the corresponding function is not executed. What I am doing wrong??

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: `break` exits the entire for loop

Comment: Your first lambda does not call `self._f` use `self._f()`

Comment: what is `type`? ` `conditions =` line is not syntactially valid as wrriten

Comment: With all the above remarks, you could simplify: `condition = lambda x: x in ['YES', 'MAYBE', 'TRY AGAIN']` and then call it via `condition(type)`. Also, you know that ***conditions* is evaluated at definition time, and changing *type* afterwards has no effect** on it.

Comment: My real problem, indepently of the variables and conditions, is how to define functions with variable arguments and call them with a unique sentence ()

Comment: You don't necessarily need lambda expressions at all. `lambda: self._f()` is just `self._f` with an extra layer of indirection around it.

Comment: You are calling *all* the functions as if they take 0 arguments, that's only true of `functions[0]` though. Did you want `lambda: self._f2(a)` and `lambda: self._f3(b, c)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps:

#### Option 1:

```py
class MyTestClass:
    def loopTest(self, type, value, value2):
        # necessary to iterate over the values later on
        possibleArgs = [value, value2]

        conditions = [type == 'YES', type == 'MAYBE', type=='TRY AGAIN']
        # here you made the mistake that the first lambda expression didnt call the function "_f" it just "looked" at the reference
        sentences = [lambda: self._f(), lambda x: self._f2(x), lambda x,y: self._f3(x, y)]

        for condition, sentence in zip(conditions, sentences):
            if condition:
                # necessary to pass the arguments to the function
                # "sentence.__code__.co_argcount" gives us the number of arguments of the function
                args = (possibleArgs[i] for i in range(sentence.__code__.co_argcount))
                sentence(*args)
                break

    def _f(self):
        print('executed')

    def _f2(self, x):
        print(f'executed with value {x}')

    def _f3(self, x, y):
        print(f'executed with values {x} and {y}')

MyTestClass().loopTest("TRY AGAIN", 5, 2)
# output: executed with values 5 and 2
```

#### Option 2:

```py
class MyTestClass:
    def loopTest(self, type, value, value2):
        a = value
        b = value2

        conditions = [type == 'YES', type == 'MAYBE', type=='TRY AGAIN']
        # here you made the mistake that the first lambda expression didnt call the function "_f" it just "looked" at the reference
        sentences = [lambda: self._f(), lambda: self._f2(a), lambda: self._f3(a, b)]

        for condition, sentence in zip(conditions, sentences):
            if condition:
                sentence()
                break

    def _f(self):
        print('executed')

    def _f2(self, x):
        print(f'executed with value {x}')

    def _f3(self, x, y):
        print(f'executed with values {x} and {y}')

MyTestClass().loopTest("TRY AGAIN", 5, 2)
# output: executed with values 5 and 2
```

Comment: OK, option 2 works fine. My error was definning x and y in lambda functions! Thanks!

Comment: I know this... Mistakes happen haha